# Passing data to an activity from a TableView

Tags: java, android, global

I have some data that is loaded from a JSON stream, I load it into a STATIC SortedList and display this information in a TableView. Each row also has an "info" type icon, when clicked it bring up a new Activity and displays more information on the row. I pass in the hash code to the SortedList to the Activity.

My problem is that in SOME situations, the activity receives the hash code BUT gets a null object back from the SortedList.

I have a class called Global, the Sorted list is a Static Member variable of this class.

Any idea what is going wrong here? It workes most of the time but my Google Analytics is catching situations where there is a problem.

Best way to implement what I want?

**** Here is the Global class I use to store the information.

```
public class Global {  
    public static LinkedHashMap<String, FSFlight> flightsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, FSFlight>();  
    public Global() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
    }  
}
```

**** Method to launch Activity

```
 public void runFlightInfo(String flightTag) {
    Intent flightInfoIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FlightInfo.class);
    flightInfoIntent.putExtra("flightTag", flightTag);
    startActivityForResult(flightInfoIntent, FLIGHTDETAILS_ACTIVITY_CONST);
}
```

**** OnStart Method in the Activity

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 flightTag = extras.getString("flightTag");


 flight = Global.flightsMap.get(flightTag);

 if (flight == null) {
        codePosition = "### Null flight retrieved - FlightTag=" + flightTag;
        Tracker myTracker = EasyTracker.getTracker();      // Get a reference to tracker.
        myTracker.sendException("FlightInfo onStart - " + codePosition, false);
        return;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Comment: Thanks @ShimonRachlenko. I have modified my original post to show the existing code. This code seems to work in most cases as it is being called a lot. However, my Google Analytics is picking up around 50 times a day where the flight object coming back from the flightsMap is null.

Comment: Any takers on this one please? Really stuck here.